# making different clocks in system generator

Tags: xilinx, xilinx-system-generator

I have a circuit in system generator which I cannot retrieve the output signal since it has a high rate. For this issue I planned to use a FIFO at the output. I wanna give the circuit clock to write-enable pin and give read-enable pin a clock with more frequency. So I want to slow down the clock of FPGA, give it to to my previous circuit and then give the clock of FPGA to read-enable pin of FIFO. I asked some days ago and someone taught me using a counter for this issue. So my problem is to decrease the frequency of FPGA's clock by using a counter. I will be thankful if someone give me a picture of the circuit drawn in system generator for this manner.

Comment: You have a clock of frequency A and you want another clock, with a frequency B. Is this correct? If so what is A/B and what is A?

Comment: @Andyaka Yes. You have understand my problem very well. The clock of FPGA is 20MHz and I want to make it 1000 times slower. I will be thankful if you guide me. Do you think that this trick will resolve the problem?

Comment: How about 1024 times slower - that's really easy?

Comment: @Andyaka it is ok

Comment: This might be what you're looking for:
https://docs.xilinx.com/r/2020.2-English/ug1483-model-composer-sys-gen-user-guide/The-Clock-Enables-Multirate-Implementation

Comment: robo_dude That doesnt seem to be relevant. Any comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get 1000 by using two of these: -

[image]

Note that it can be configured to divide its input frequency by either 10 or 100. Putting two of these in series will produce a total clock frequency divider of 1000. If 1024 can be used then it's even easier because \$2^{10}\$ is 1024 so you need a ten stage ripple counter such as the [74HC4040](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT4040.pdf) (OK it happens to have 12 stages but just ignore the outputs from stage 11 and 12). Power for both types is between 2V and 6V and don't forget to provide a 100nF power decoupling capacitor on the power rails at the chip.

### For clock frequencies over 1GHz: -

At the further end of the scale, if you had clock frequencies over 1GHz then there is the [AD9515](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9515.pdf) - it can be set to divide by 10 and you'd need two (or possibly one followed by some very fast "normal" CMOS divider). The AD9515 is also a dual counter with a common input clock suitable for LVDS or PECL etc - it can be coupled capacitively.

### D type divider for use in xilinx system generator: -

[image]

Q0 is CLOCK divided by 2 - each subsequent D type divides the clock by a further two. Q2 is clock divided by 4. Cascade 10 D types as shown above to get divide by 1024 or \$2^{10}\$.

Comment: can you give me more information in system generator environment?

Comment: I don't understand the question - Are you looking for some scripting language suitable for xylinx? Would it be easier if you just had a bunch of D type flip-flops cascaded?

Comment: I should write the VHDL code for this matter, but as I do not know very much about this programming language I have planned to do it by System Generator and generate its VHDL code via that.

Comment: I've never used system generator - so this means it's the blind leading the uninformed LOL. Do you have D type flip flop building blocks? Or any flip-flop types? Do you understand my "blind" question?

Comment: Yes. I have D type flip flop block

Comment: OK then I'll add a little picture to my answer on how to cascade them to get 1024